# Group (in)flexion (Gruppenflexion) in Slavic?

Tags: terminology, cases, slavic-languages, declension

Even in works by Slavic linguists, when the concept of group infexion is discussed (eg Mel'čuk) the examples are from "exotic" languages (some also mention the English possessive 's, though I think Mel'čuk at times said that this is a different phenomenon).  What seems clear to me (and I would like some help, input, etc.) is that this is perfectly common in Slavic, tho in somewhat special and restricted contexts.  Moreover, the grammars sometimes mention one or two examples, but do not really come to grips with the phenomenon, which seems complex.  Moreover, in some cases it is condemned either by grammarians or sometimes by people contradicting the specialists.  So vocative phrases like pane (voc.) Novák (seemingly nom.) in Czech are accepted by grammarians but the net is full of busybodies telling people not to say that.  But it is quite complex and I don't want to waste time redoing work that maybe someone else has done that I just missed. The vocative is just one type of construction where we find this.  It occurs in all cases.  In Russian often with Name + Patronymic.  In Russian, Czech, Polish I am sure (in others I haven't looked) it is common with phrases, part of which is a foreign name, more so if it is a woman's foreign name, also in phrases like including a masculine title used for a woman. Ex. in either Czech or Polish (likely also Russian) would be Alexandra (genitive) Borgia (uninflected), though inflected genitive Borgi is also possible.  But there are other names where inflection is outright impossible, so there is no one simple single pattern.  Plus as I said and as the first comment I received proves, the world is full of people who just cannot bear to discuss what the FACTS are but must immediately lecture everyone.  Please people I am asking about the FACTS and also about any linguistic literature on the subject.  Oh yes and just because I MAY be the first linguist to realize that this is precisely Gruppenflexion, does not mean that it doesn't exist.  Thank you.

Comment: Is your question only about the Slavic vocative case or you know of and want to discuss other examples of Slavic Gruppenflexion? I know there's no Gruppenflexion in the Slavic languages, the vocative case example only shows the tendency of the vocative case to disappear with the formal official grammars trying to support it while the colloquial usage shows the signs of its decay.

Comment: It is not true in Slavic generally that the viocative is disappearing, so plz people stop spreading blatant misinformation.  And in general the phenomenon I am after is not restricted to the vocative, no.  F.ex. in Russian name+patronymic combinations (tho not all of them) often have the first part uninflected in any case.

Comment: It is not true in Russian that the name+patronymic combinations often have the first part uninflected in any case.

Comment: @AttilathePun are you talking about the Russian neo-vocative (e.g. Лен for Лена)? This is unconnected to the historical vocative so it would still be accurate to say the vocative is disappearing (just that a new vocative is, in some analyses, developing)